# Как сделать горизонтальный RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

[image: Карточки на RecyclerView]

Здраствуй любой сюда входящий, я хотел бы узнать какие образом можно создать такие карточки и как сделать RecyclerView вертикальной прокруткой. Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Используйте такой мэнеджер: `LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а что за значение context?

Comment: Очень долго и сложно объяснять. ПОпробуйте `this` использовать